# WordPress Contact Form 7 Regex validation handles differently than online regex testers?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, validation, contact-form-7

Working in **WordPress** using **Contact Form 7** plugin trying to validate an input
starting at '€ 5000' with steps of 5000. So possible inputs are "€ 10.000", "€ 15.000", "€ 255000" etc.

Input values like "€ 2000", "€ 5050" should be **FALSE**.

The expression i built using the online regex tester works (php)

> /^[€]\s(1?[5]000|[1-9]{1}[5,0]{1,3}([0]{3,10}))$/

see for **working example** -> https://regex101.com/r/PvqlES/2

While it's working in the regex101 environment when i import the exact regex into my WordPress function in functions.php it doesn't validate as expected.

Here's my function written at bottom of functions.php:

```
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text*', 'validate_price', 20, 2);
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text', 'validate_price', 20, 2);

function validate_price( $result, $tag ) {
    if( 'participationPrice' == $tag->name) {
        $participationPrice = isset( $_POST['participationPrice'] ) ? trim( $_POST['participationPrice'] ) : '';
        if (!preg_match("/^[€]\s(1?[5]000|[1-9]{1}[5,0]{1,3}([0]{3,10}))$/g", $participationPrice)){
            $result->invalidate( $tag, "Please provide a value similar to '€ 5000' with steps of 5000." );
        }
    }
 return $result;
}
```

Here's the Contact Form 7 tag:

```
[text* participationPrice]
```

The form does indeed check for validation as it's showing the error message:

[error message validates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju01p.png)

The question: Why do online regex testers validate properly but once imported to WordPress it won't validate properly. I can only assume the regex needs some tweaking so WordPress can make sense of it. What am i doing wrong / missing?

I **tested** using a very simple regex to see if it would go through:

> /^[0-9]{0,1}$/

This regex does however work as expected.

Bonus, if there is a better way to validate, like say input must be dividable by 5000. That would be a way better validation as i'm sure the current regex has a lot of loopholes.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: FYI: Do not use `g` modifier with PHP regexps. Also, try `if (!preg_match("/^€\s*(1?5000|[1-9][5,0]{1,3}0{3,10})$/u", ...))`. IF you want to find out if the number is dividable, extract all prices, `preg_match_all('~^€\s*\K\d+$~u', $s, $matches)` and then use appropriate PHP method to check if the numbers in `$matches[1]` are dividable by 5000.

Comment: You're quick! Thank you, i will test this later today. I went to take some fresh air after puzzling all day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just extract any numbers from your strings using `'~€\s*\K\d+~u'` regex and then filter the resulting array using a simple check if the number can be divided by `5000`:

```
$s = "€ 5000\n€ 3000\n€ 10000\n€ 13000\n€ 20000\n\n€ 5000\n€ 3000\n€ 100000\n\n€ 13000\n€ 200000\n\n€ 200000000000\n\n\n€ 255000\n€ 2555000\n€ 255000";
if (preg_match_all('~€\s*\K\d+~u',$s, $matches)) {
    print_r(array_filter($matches[0], function ($m) { return $m % 5000 === 0; }));
}
```

The pattern `€\s*\K\d+` matches `€`, then 0+ whitespace chars (with `\s*`), then the matches chars are discarded with `\K` match reset operator, and then `\d+` matches 1  or more digits.

Output of the [sample PHP demo](https://ideone.com/JKX5nx):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5000
    [2] => 10000
    [4] => 20000
    [5] => 5000
    [7] => 100000
    [9] => 200000
    [10] => 200000000000
    [11] => 255000
    [12] => 2555000
    [13] => 255000
)
```